# Xcode - Button increment label

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uilabel

I want to create a button in my ios project.

This button will work for count from 1 to 200(or any above)

Each press of the button, label will increase

When you first click, label = 1
when you second click, label = 2
.
.
.

I created a button and a label.

In button IBAction what should I do?

Answer (score 6):

```
-(IBAction)count {
    int x = [[label text] intValue];
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x+1]];
}
```

However, you should try to search for some tutorials in internet. The web is full of examples and guides on iOS programming.
First of all: [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/)

Comment: +1 for a correct answer, -1 for enabling such a "gimme teh codez" question.

Comment: @Abizem: +1 to your comment. I was trying to edit the answer adding something like STFW, but my connection fell. Guess it doesn't matter anymore, but I edit the post

Comment: Fair enough - I'll +1 anyway. Actually this is only one answer, another answer is to use the MVC pattern and have the button click increment a NSUInteger iVar and then refresh the value of the label with this iVar.

Comment: Another way would be to make `x` static, and just increase it every time you click the button, removing the need to parse the string to an integer, admittedly, that isn't that big of a performance issue, but it could help.

Comment: Saphorist thanks for your answer I have one more question.

I want my button to do two functions, is it possible?

First one is counting from one to 200.... as you explain before

Second one is, Open new form. via modal or push ?

If it is possible. Could you tell me how to do that.

Comment: See? This is what happens when you feed the [vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). @B777-300ER maybe if you tried to do some of this yourself and posted some of your code you'd get better help, and you might learn something yourself.